# Salesforce Git Repository using VS Code

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, cicd

I am trying to set up the Git Repo for our Salesforce instance, we are trying to use VS Code. This is my first time setting up and never used the ANT migration tool. We do manual Change set deployment from one instance to other. Most of the article I found online on the Version Controlling are based on ANT scripts and they recommend having got handle on the ANT Script. As I have not used it before I wanted to understand for setting up CI/CD pipeline in Azure do we need to use ANT scripts? I tried getting the metadata using the VS Code and I get the ant-salesforce.jar file an all.

Can anyone recommend if I am getting the metadata using VS Code how can I set up the Pipelines without ANT migration Tools or scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you check [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) than the ANT migration toolkit.

ANT migration toolkit requires some scripting while Salesforce CLI makes it easier as it provides a lot of utilities to make metadata migration easier.

Check the below short video on how to retrieve metadata from org using the [VSCode Extension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHtdsOjuOHE&list=PLgIMQe2PKPSJdFGHjGpjd1FbCsOqq5H8t&index=28) pack for Salesforce and Salesforce CLI.

Also for using Azure pipeline check this helpful [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPGaVO72I1s)

Comment: Can we still use the sfdx & Salesforce CLI for Version Controlling and the Pipelines without starting to use the Scratch orgs?

Comment: Yes for sure! Scratch org is not required!

Comment: Can you please help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341235/salesforce-azure-deployment-pipeline here I did try to setup the pipeline and can suggest if I am missing something

Answer (score 3):

Ant isn't the preferred method in modern development. The new design uses [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx) instead. There's a lot of blogs out there (like [this one](http://theapexhub.com/ci-cd-setup-using-azure-devops-salesforce-dx-and-visual-studio-code/), not mine), plus tools like [sfpowerscripts](https://dxatscale.gitbook.io/sfpowerscripts/) (again, not mine). You just need to do some research.

Comment: Can we still use the sfdx & Salesforce CLI for Version Controlling and the Pipelines without starting to use the Scratch orgs?

Comment: @user81642 Yes, we use it that way now (but not with Azure).

Comment: Just last question, do you all set up a System Administartor service account seperately for authenticating the Connected App Setup in Salesforce for Devops Process

Comment: @user81642 We don't have a CI/CD set up currently, but if we did, we would likely have a dedicated service account for the CI/CD.